# Переопределение модификатора доступа, проблемы с наследованием (QWT)

Tags: c++, qt

Работаю с графической библиотекой QWT на Qt(C++): написал свой класс

```
class Plot : public QwtPlot 
{  ...
  QwtPlotPanner *panner;
   ...
};
```

с использованием объектов и методов различных классов библиотеки QWT ( в том числе QwtPlotPanner)

Возникла необходимость воспользоваться методом `moveCanvas()` класса `QwtPlotPanner`:

```
class QWT_EXPORT QwtPlotPanner: public QwtPanner
{
  ...
  protected Q_SLOTS:
  virtual void moveCanvas( int dx, int dy );
  ...
};
```

Для того чтобы вытащить `protected` метод в публичный доступ, создал дочерний класс-наследник от `QwtPlotPaner`, и заменил в базовом классе `Plot`  объект класса `QwtPlotPaner` на дочерний (дочерний класс ведь наследует все методы и свойства класса родителя?):

```
class QwtPlotPannerChild : public QwtPlotPanner
{
public:
    virtual void moveCanvas(int dx,int dy);
};
```

Класс Plot выглядит теперь так:

```
class Plot : public QwtPlot 
{
  ...
  QwtPlotPannerChild  *panner;
  ...
};
```

Но теперь возникла непонятная ошибка:

> ошибка: no matching function for call to
>   'QwtPlotPanner::QwtPlotPanner()'
>        class PanningCanvas : public QwtPlotPanner

Может ли кто-нибудь объяснить в чем причина, мне казалось я действую верно (судя по всему - нет)?
Спасибо

Comment: Подозреваю, что  QwtPlotPanner не имеет конструктор по умолчанию

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У класса `QwtPlotPanner` есть `explicit` конструктор, который Вы обязаны предоставить. Если пользуетесь современным компилятором, то достаточно:
`using QwtPlotPanner::QwtPlotPanner`, если нет, тогда:

```
QwtPlotPannerChild(QwtPlotCanvas* canvas): QwtPlotPanner(canvas)
{
}
```

Ну и переопределять `moveCanvas` не нужно, если не собираетесь менять поведения. Достаточно `using QwtPlotPanner::moveCanvas;` в `public` секции.

Comment: Я бы указал аргумент по умолчанию  QwtPlotCanvas* canvas = 0

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, на каком основании? Класс-родитель явно требует ненулевого указателя, мы не имеем права нарушать контракт.

Comment: я  не понел вашу мысль.  При нулевом родительском указателе просто родитель не играет роль. Почему  же класс родитель явно требует ненулевой указатель?  Что я упускаю?..

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, `QwtPlotPanner` требует ненулевой указатель. Как мы можем туда null передать? Он, по-Вашему, готов к такой ситуации? Если бы ему подходил нулевой указатель, то у него бы был конструктор с параметром по умолчанию, но у него его нет.